# countif syntahx in vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops, countif

I was coding a loop, and i was wondering why my macro doesn't work. The idea of the macro is to determine the month's number of weeks. With knowing the name of the fisrt workday of a month i can countif the number of this occurence in a range of week's day. Her it is :

```
Dim dbNbSemaines As Double
Dim strAbrevJourMois As String

strAbrevJourMois = Range("E4").Value

If strAbrevJourMois = "lun" Then
Range("A404").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""lun"")"
    dbNbSemaines = Range("A404").Value

ElseIf strAbrevJourMois = "mar" Then
    Range("A404").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""mar"")"
    dbNbSemaines = Range("A404").Value

ElseIf strAbrevJourMois = "mer" Then
    Range("A404").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""mer"")"
    dbNbSemaines = Range("A404").Value

ElseIf strAbrevJourMois = "jeu" Then
    Range("A404").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""jeu"")"
    dbNbSemaines = Range("A404").Value

ElseIf strAbrevJourMois = "ven" Then
    Range("A404").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""ven"")"
    dbNbSemaines = Range("A404").Value
```

End If

When i go to the A404 cell that contains the countif formula it returns a `#NOM?` and it contains a `=NB.SI('E4':'AB4';"lun")`. How can i write it in vba to insert the range E4:AB4 in the COUNTIF formula ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `NB.SI` in place of `COUNTIF`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - VBA's [.Formula](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) and [.FormulaR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527.aspx) expect [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34). To use regional language function 'flavors' like [NB.SI](https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/NB-SI-NB-SI-fonction-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) then the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) should be employed instead.

Comment: @Jeeped ............thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simple select case is enough I think.

```
Dim dbNbSemaines As Long
Dim strAbrevJourMois As String

strAbrevJourMois = LCase(Range("E4").Value)

Select Case strAbrevJourMois
    Case Is = "lun", "mar", "mer", "jeu", "ven"
        Range("A404").Formula = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""" & strAbrevJourMois & """)"
        dbNbSemaines = Range("A404").Value
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
Range("A404").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""lun"")"
```

to

```
Range("A404").Formula = "=COUNTIF(E4:AB4,""lun"")"
```

(the same for the other formulas)

If you want to stick to `.FormulaR1C1 then you would have to write

```
Range("A404").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R[-400]C[4]:R[-400]C[27],""lun"")"
```